# Splitting and reconnecting lists

Tags: python, numpy

What I'm trying to accomplish is getting the list to split at a random point and join the second part of another list to it. The code that is attached will start the list with a randomly generated element that is made of 0's and 1's but contains 10 of them. Then the next 10 elements are random 0's and 1's that are a length of 5. When I try to split them I get this error: ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions

Example of what I'm hoping to get is:

```
p1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10][1,1,1,0,0][0,0,0,1,1]
p2 =[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20][0,1,1,0,0][0,1,0,1,0]
k1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,1,1,0,0] ,(split between p1 and p2) [0,1,0,1,0]
k2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],(split between p1 and p2 This will be random)[1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1]
```

The error is coming at this line : `kid1 = np.hstack([p1[:index1],p2[index1:]])`

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def generateRandom(Population , m):
    i = 0
    population = []
    while (i < Population):
        array_first= [np.random.randint (2, size = 10)]
        array_outer = np.random.randint(2,size=(m-1,5))
        array_first.extend(array_outer)
        population.append(array_first)
        i += 1
    return(population)

def mating (parents):
    parent1_array = []
    parent2_array= []
    for i in range (int(len(parents)/2)):
        parent1 = parents[i]
        parent2 = parents[-i-1]
        parent1_array.append(parent1)
        parent2_array.append(parent2)
    return (parent1_array, parent2_array)


def crossover (parent1, parent2, mutate):
    kid1_array = []
    kid2_array = []
    kids = []
    for p1,p2 in zip(parent1, parent2):
        index1 = int(np.random.uniform(low=1,high=len(p1)-1))
        index2 = int(np.random.uniform(low=1, high=len(p2)-1))           
        kid1 = np.hstack([p1[:index1],p2[index1:]])
        kid2 = np.hstack([p2[:index2],p1[index2:]])
        kid1_array.append(kid1)
        kid2_array.append(kid2)
        kids.extend((kid1,kid2))
    for individual in kids:
        if (mutate > random.random()):
            pos_to_mutate = random.randint(0, len(individual)-1)
            individual[pos_to_mutate] =random.uniform(min(individual),max(individual))
    return (kids)



candidateSolution = generateRandom(100, 11)
for i in range(1):
    a = random.random() 
    parent1 , parent2 = mating(candidateSolution)
    kids = crossover( parent1 , parent2, .01 )
```

The outcome I'd hope to get would be the two kid list would be parts of parent1 and parent2 that were split at some random point and then recombined.

Comment: What line is giving the error?  Post the whole stacktrace.  Also, post actual example input and desired output.

Comment: @huck_cussler added what you asked for. The input would be random due to the call function and the output would be the random split but examples were added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message is self explanatory:

> all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions

`p1` and `p2` have that unnumpyesque shape [(1, 10), (10, 5)] making that kind of error inevitable. either use one-dimensional genomes (60,) or make all your chromosomes of the same length (12, 5). but the way it is now, numpy will never accept to stack them.

Comment: well dang... I'm setting it up for a recreation of a set of data just given their information and that is the best I could make out of it. Thanks for that information. I'll have to see what I can find.

Comment: Is there any way around this kind of idea?